# replace number with star specific pattern for whole file

Tags: grep, sed, awk

In my file I want to replace number to `*`

Example:

```
data[0] ---> data[*]
```

I have `data[0]` to `data[127]` and also want to do for the whole file.
So how can I do only for number?

I tried with command

```
sed 's/[[0-9][0-9]]/[*]/g'
```

but it does not work properly.

So please guide me.

Comment: why shouldn't it be as simple as `sed 's/[0-9]/*/g` ?

Comment: It will also affect other number also. Suppose  set_load -pin_load 0.5 [get_ports {data[25]}]  then it will also change 0.5 to *.

Comment: The issue in what you tried is not escaping square brackets when you don't want them to have a special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all digits inside square brackets to asterisks:

```
sed 's/\[[0-9]*\]/\[*\]/g'
```

Comment: I believe there's no need to escape the square brackets in the replacement section, as they have no special meaning there.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** Here's how you could amend your tentative SED expression (`sed 's/[[0-9][0-9]]/[*]/g'`):

```
sed -E 's/\[[0-9]{1,3}]/[*]/g'
```

**Explanation:**

- escape the initial square bracket `[` with a backslash `\` because you want the expression to match a literal `[` as opposed to any of the characters you write between square brackets. Subsequent square brackets do not need escaping.
- specify how many digits you want to match: `{1,3}` means any natural number starting with `1` and up to `3`. For this to work, you need to enable *extended regular expressions* with the `-E` switch (without it you could be content with `sed 's/\[[0-9]*]/[*]/g'`). It should be available in your `sed` since, according to `man sed`:

  > the -E option has been supported for years by GNU sed, and is now included in POSIX.

---

Perl alternative here:

```
perl -pe 's/data\[\K\d+(?=])/*/g'
```